# What does "hand-up" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I was interviewed for a job at a company X by the manager of team A. This was meant to be a final interview. However, this person wrote in an email, talking about me to the recruiter:

> The interview went well, and he seems like a good fit for our company X. However, he's likely to **hand-up working** with team B rather than my team. As a result, can Luis have a brief discussion with *name* who manages team B?

What does this mean? Did he not find me a good fit for team A, or is the fact that I will end up in team B something he doesn't necessarily choose?

It probably helps to say that the manager of team A is french so **not** a native english speaker.

Comment: It sounds like a typo (perhaps autocomplete mistake?) for “end up.”

Comment: I've never come across "hand up" in this context. Is it an error for "end up"? There could be many reasons; perhaps you would be good for A but even better for B.

Comment: He is a non-native english speaker so from your comments I assume it was an error then. However, I believe it is more like him using "hand-up" wrong than it being a typo. From the rest of the phrase do you think you can guess what he meant?

Comment: Yes, we both guessed "end up" from context. I could guess a few other meanings, but they would be wilder guesses, and not indicated by anything in the text. For example, I could imagine that the author meant "he's likely to *prefer* working with Team B." But if so, he did not communicate that successfully. It's possible, as an English learner, that he made a direct translation from his original language that didn't have a direct equivalent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a typo (or perhaps over-zealous spell/style-checker) substituting ***hand-up*** for ***end up***.

Comment: Fire that guy. Hire the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the manager was a non-native speaker, I think he made a typo. I think he meant **end up** instead of **hand-up**.

> What does this mean? Did he not find me a good fit for team A, or is the fact that I will end up in team B something he doesn't necessarily choose?

It is hard to tell since the person who wrote it did not clarify whether it was his choice or another persons choice.

As I would interpret it, he thinks you fit ***better*** for team B because of your technical knowledge (or whatever your work area is) rather than you did not fit in at team A. He also said in the beginning that the interview went well, and you were a good fit for the company, which means he is positive about you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you meant "non-native speaker" as opposed to "non-english speaker". Anyone who speaks English is an English speaker :)

Comment: @EddieKal You're right, thanks. I edited the answer ;)

Comment: non-english speaker hahahaha love that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Luismi98 Of course, no problem